# ServerSocket receives no data in a loop

Tags: java, serversocket

I use ServerSocket to get data from client in a while loop, it works at the first run, but fails after second round.

I did some search but still can't figure out what happened.

Server side code

```
package com.gorilla.main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(44444);

        while(true){

        System.out.println("another round");

        Socket socket  = serverSocket.accept();
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

        System.out.println("available: "+ inputStream.available());

        byte[] b = new byte[inputStream.available()];

        inputStream.read(b);

        System.out.println(new String(b));
        System.out.println("=======================");

        socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Clent side code

```
package com.gorilla.main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client2 {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{

        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 44444);
        String s = "Hello World";
        byte [] b = s.getBytes();
        socket.getOutputStream().write(b);;
        socket.close();

    }
}
```

and the output at Server side console after I ran client 3 times.

```
another round
available: 11
Hello World
=======================
another round
available: 0

=======================
another round
available: 0

=======================
another round
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`InputStream.available()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) to size your buffer and that's not how one reads from a socket. You should allocate a buffer (usually sized statically, or maybe configurable) and read in a loop

```
// server code
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
  // do something
}
```

The Javadoc of `InputStream.available():`

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or
>   skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next
>   invocation of a method for this input stream. The next invocation
>   might be the same thread or another thread. A single read or skip of
>   this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.

If your protocol is text-based, you can wrap the socket's input stream inside a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and thus the loop becomes

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scanner.next();
}
```

Comment: It works. But why I can read something from an inputStream when inputStream.available() is 0? Do you have ideas?

Comment: Your use case doesn't require `available()`. Just read (it's a blocking call) and configure the timeout